# Cloud Build trigger changes file permissions and breaks docker caching

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I am using `google-cloud-build` as CI to test if a PR breaks the build or not.

The build is basically creating a Docker image.
To reduce the build time, I am trying to use dockers `--cache-from` feature, but it fails for me on a `COPY ...` because when using a `Github App trigger`, most file permissions are changed for some reason.
When using a `Github trigger`, this issue does not happen, but I cannot trigger it on a PR as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers).

Is there a way to prevent from cloud build to change file permissions when using a `Github App trigger`? is there another way to solve this?

Comment: I was attempting to check if the file permission changed and the permissions changes but preserving the ones you've already set up. Do you know from what permissions to which others are the files being changed?

Comment: Sorry @FerVelvet Didn't map it exactly, just saw differences :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, we decided that this is fine and if we want specific file permissions on a file, we will manually set them in the docker file using `RUN chmod ...`

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I've found that actually Cloud Build does not change the file permissions. Those are preserved from the origin where Cloud Build is getting the resources but I've found that it seems that GitHub changes those permissions.

I had 2 files with the permissions `-r--r--r--` and when I pushed them to GitHub then in Cloud Build I could see that those files had the permissions `-rw-rw-r--`. Then To be sure what was happening, I cloned the repo in another site and the files that were pulled from the repo had the permissions `-rw-rw-r--`. So the cause seems to be GitHub.

As you mentioned in your answer, the best approach is to change permissions at build time.